# Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Double>' to expected argument type 'Int'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm a new comer with SwiftUI.
now I need to use   @Binding var movie : Movie in edit view which binded with List page,
but when I apply it to the code below, Err just happened.

`Text("Current Progress: \($movie.grenzen * 100, specifier: "%.0f") %")`

***Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to expected argument type 'Int'***

then what shall I do with this case,
looking forward for your kind help.

by the way, how could I use Binding type in "progress" like this,
`ProgressView("Progress", value: $movie.grenzen, total: 1)`
it also reports Err,
*Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Binding'*

I got another problem , since I use movie.grenze. when I press the "Increment Progress" button, the progress bar doesn't change.

`Button("Increment Progress") { if movie.grenzen < 1 { movie.grenzen += 0.1 } }`

hope there's any further support for this,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bindings are generally used when you need two-way communication, meaning both sides need to be able to modify the value. In both of the cases you've listed, you don't, in fact, need a binding.

For example, in your first case, `Text` isn't going to edit the value -- just display it. So, don't use the `$`:

```
Text("Current Progress: \(movie.grenzen * 100, specifier: "%.0f") %")
```

Similarly, in the second case, `ProgressView` does not take a `Binding` either:

```
ProgressView("Progress", value: movie.grenzen, total: 1)
```

This is assuming that `movie.grenzen` is a `Float` or `Double`

Comment: appreciate for your help, I got another problem , since I use movie.grenze. when I press the "Increment Progress" button, the progress bar doesn't change. `           Button("Increment Progress") {
              if movie.grenzen < 1 {
                movie.grenzen += 0.1
              }
            }`

Comment: @GaryZou there's not enough here for me to diagnose that next problem. It would probably be a good idea to create a new question with it, including a [mre]. Specifically, I'd need to see the type that `movie` is and how it's connected to the `Button` (ie is it in a `@StateObject` or something like that. I or someone else will try to help from there!

Comment: Sir, appreciate for your kindly reply. i will update the question content via the entire page coding later on, have good day!!

Comment: Sure — make a new question though — not an update to this one. Will be happy to look at it.

Comment: hi i already revise my question here cause i have no privilege to throw up a new question. please have look ^-^

Comment: Unfortunately, now my current answer makes no sense for what is up here in the edited version. And, there’s still not enough code there for me to reproduce the issue. Also, questions should focus on *one* issue at a time. Please wait until you can put another question up and do that and revise this question back to it’s original state. It’s likely to get closed otherwise.

Comment: I get it that in this example presented binding is not need, but what if you did need binding? I need to get a var defined as `@Binding var iconSize: Double = 32.0` and convert it to a Int for use in an image.

Comment: @tgunr Please start a new question with the relevant code included.